# Why "main" thread doesn't wait while another thread do in synchronized method

Tags: java, multithreading

If I correct understand method with `synchronized` word lock `this` object and any others threads will wait while executing `synchronized` method, and any another method close for executing, any method within object, while object lock.

Example code:

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        User user = new User();
        user.setAge(10);
        user.setData("data");

        Thread thread = new Thread(new ChildThread(user));
        thread.start();

        PI.print(Thread.currentThread(), user.getData());
    }
}




public class ChildThread implements Runnable {

    private User user;

    public ChildThread(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Integer age = user.getAge();
        PI.print(Thread.currentThread(), age.toString());

    }
}



public class User {

private Integer age;
private String data;

public synchronized Integer getAge() {
    try {
            System.out.println("Blocked");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            System.out.println("Stop sleep");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return age;
}

public void setAge(Integer age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public synchronized String getData() { //synchranized on the same object
    return data;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;

    }
 }

public class PI {

public static void print(Thread thread, String age) {
    System.out.println("Name: " + thread.getName() + " res: " + age);
}
}
```

Will output next result:

```
Blocked
Name: main res: data
Stop sleep
Name: Thread-0 res: 10
```

Why does 'main' thread doesn't wait while end execute another thread?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you mean by the main not waiting, what would you have it wait for?
Usually when birthing threads and wanting to wait for them to finish their execution "join" is used.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html

Comment: For 'main' thread from main() method wait while 'child' thread executing method. 

But I decide this question, basically 'main' thread works quickly then 'child' even if code place was writed previously. If 'main' thread wait some small time (10 mills) lock on object works correct.